# How can I retrieve autofill password from Google Chrome after Windows refreshed wiped it all?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I did a windows system refresh and didn't realize it was going to completely wipe out all my data.

I need a password to a blockchain wallet it was in my google chrome autofill, but it has to be from may 30th or before, I don't have a restore point I tried everything. I read maybe something with mysql database it's possible to retrieve the old autofill password?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a Google account connected to Chrome? If so, you can just log in, and it will work again.

If not, May 30th is a long time ago. Maybe you are able to restore files with [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva)? Search for this folder:
`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`